# Tree insert function not recognizing node that is None type

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Trying to write a binary search tree in python with different functions. One of the function is a simple "insert" node.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
    def insert(self, root, val):
        if root is None:
            return Node(val)
        if val < root.val:
            root.left = self.insert(root.left, val)
        elif root.val < val:
            root.right = self.insert(root.right, val)
        return root
```

Seems pretty simple but when I create a Node object:

```
root= Node()
```

and tried inserting it with:

```
root = root.insert(root,30)
```

I am getting an error saying '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'

I am already trying to take care of it in the insert function by checking `if root is None:` How can I fix this?

Comment: you're testing if `root` is None, you probably want to test `root.val`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`if root is None or root.val is None:`

...since `root.val` may be `None`

You could also do `if None in (root, root.val):`